# Detect who try to unlock screen by webcam

Tags: webcam, unlock

Is there a easy way to detect somebody who try to unlock screen by webcam?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **:-)**  Interesting question, but no: it's not going to be *easy...*  **;-)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fabby!